# Plugin with id 'maven' not found

Tags: java, gradle

> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

I got this error in IDEA that uses with 7.1, that is strange as `maven` is built-in plugin, and should be distributed with gradle.

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
```

When running Gradle 6.3, it seems there is no such error.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

In Gradle 7.x,

> The maven plugin has been removed. You should use the maven-publish
> plugin instead.

**Reference:** https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#removal_of_the_legacy_maven_plugin

Comment: sir, I'm new to react-native
it stuck in build.gredle file "repository url: "file://${projectDir}/../android/maven", i dont know why?

Comment: please provide full example, I'm new to gradle, can't understand in which part of file I need do changes. thank you

Answer (score 45):

Search for the file build.gradle. It should be in your project directory and change the

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
```

to

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

Comment: In addition to this, there may also be some code that needs altering, but that will vary from project to project.

Comment: my code doesnt even have  "apply plugin: 'maven' ". i added the maven publish, but still errors out

Comment: @not_fubar_yet you may not have this in the project, but in my case, this was in the used old plugin, which caused an error

Answer (score 23):

The maven plugin was [removed](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#removal_of_the_legacy_maven_plugin) in Gradle 7. The documentation suggests to use `maven-publish` plugin instead.

Comment: I guess you don't really need tracking for the link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25036210/how-to-remove-ga-query-string-from-url/

Comment: _ga parameter removed.

Comment: please provide full example, I'm new to gradle, can't understand in which part of file I need do changes. thank you

Answer (score 6):

As the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html#removal_of_the_legacy_maven_plugin) says that the *maven plugin was removed and to use the maven-publish plugin instead*

Another approach was to use the *gradle wrapper* with version less than 7. Since wrapper is customizable. Creating a wrapper could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25770202/13855094)

So for example
`gradle clean build`
is equivalent to
`./gradlew clean build`

Since the version of wrapper is less than 7 every task can be ran with the help of `./gradlew <task>` or `./gradlew.bat <task>`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same Error when I tried to build a Project.
The problem was The Gradle version

my  Gradle version was above 7 and it showed id 'maven' not found error.

Android Studio go to File->Project Structure and select:

> Android Gradle Plugin Version: 4.2.2
> Gradle Version: 6.7.1

This seems to make things work again.

[Refer github](https://github.com/auth0/react-native-auth0/issues/403#issuecomment-908874945)